# Applying "iconv" to all PHP files in all subdirectories

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu, files, directory, php

I am trying to change the files in many subdirectories.

The following processes the current directory only:

```
for file in *.php; do 
    iconv -f cp949 -t utf8 -o "$file.new" "$file" && mv -f "$file.new" "$file"
done
```

How may I apply this to all PHP files in all subdirectories?

Comment: At the risk of being blunt, the users here are generally not your servants, so making demands may not be the best course of action. You're better off trying to fix your code yourself.

Comment: You clearly have something that works for a group of files in a single directory. You may `find` more help if you show your attempt at extending that to solve the problem at hand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a number of subdirectories in the current directory and that they contain the `.php` files:

```
for file in */*.php; do 
    iconv -f cp949 -t utf8 -o "$file.new" "$file" && mv -f "$file.new" "$file"
done
```

Assuming you have a deep directory hierarchy and you'd like to find all the `.php` files anywhere in it:

```
find . -type f -name '*.php' \
    -exec sh -c 'file="$0"; iconv -f cp949 -t utf8 -o "$file.new" "$file" && mv -f "$file.new" "$file"' {} ';'
```

The above suggestions are untested.